# Daterangepicker min date

Tags: daterangepicker

I have module that has delivery date and I used the daterangepicker for my delivery date. I want to set my daterangepicker current year until 10 yrs from now

**JS**

```
$('#date_needed').append(''
  +'<input type="text" class="form-control dates_edit" name="date_needed" />'
)

$('.dates_edit').daterangepicker({
                yearRange: '2019:c+10',
                singleDatePicker: true,
                minDate: new Date('2019:c+10'),
                showDropdowns: true
            });
```

Question: How can I make my min date for my date_needed daterangepicker?

Answer (score 1):

```
minDate: new Date(new Date().setFullYear(new Date().getFullYear() + 10))
```

Comment: Do you really mean + 20?  The OP has asked for 10.

Comment: your can add there , based on your requirement.
if you need 10 replace 20 with 10 years.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, it will start now 2029 - 2034. I want 2019 - 2029

Comment: minDate : new Date(),
maxDate: new Date(new Date().setFullYear(new Date().getFullYear() + 10))

mindata and maxdate both are the daterangepicker contols , 
you can set minimum date what you required from i.e (2019) and 
as well as maxdate is the end date of your datepicker 
in your case 

(2019) is mindate
(2029) is Maxdate

Comment: So youre saying is my maxDate should be like the answer above, while my minDate without +10?

Comment: maxDate: new Date(new Date().setFullYear(new Date().getFullYear() +10))

Comment: yes, like this minDate : new Date(), maxDate: new Date(new Date().setFullYear(new Date().getFullYear() + 10))

Comment: Care to explain why my code didnt work? I just separated it into my maxDate:

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @RaviTeja V my problem is now solved by doing this:

```
$('.dates_edit').daterangepicker({
       yearRange: '2019:c+10',
       singleDatePicker: true,
       minDate : new Date(), maxDate: new Date(new Date().setFullYear(new Date().getFullYear() + 10)),
       showDropdowns: true
});
```

But can someone explain to me,why my code below didn't work?

```
$('.dates_edit').daterangepicker({
        yearRange: '2019:c+10',
        singleDatePicker: true,
        minDate: new Date(new Date().setFullYear(new Date().getFullYear())),
        maxDate: new Date(new Date().setFullYear(new Date().getFullYear() +10)),
        showDropdowns: true

});
```

Is there any difference between the two?